# Modelling selective inheritance trait in Java?

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question. Please correct it if I'm wrong.

I have 3 classes that models inheritance where some subclasses should not inherit a parent attribute.

Let's take for example the below classes:

```
abstract public class Root{
    // Has some attributes that must be inherited by it's sub classes
    List<Child> children;
}

abstract public class Child extends Root {
    // Has the root's attributes, plus additional attributes pertaining to the child class, including the position.
    private int position;
}

abstract public class Leaf extends Child {
    // this class inherits all attributes of child class but it does not have any children
    // How would I exclude the children attribute here?
}
```

I was thinking about using an interface but then it doesn't allow me to hold mutable data for the classes like an abstract class can. For example, I want to hold specific variables pertaining to the Child and Leaf class, such as the position of the child in the list of its parent.

I can't do this either:

```
abstract public class Leaf {
    // This child does not have a parent, but then again, it's not considered a child either because it comes before the Root who has children.
}

abstract public class Root extends Leaf {
    List<Child> children;
}

abstract public class Child extends Root {
    private int position;
}
```

Again, how would I model this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple flip of not having `Leaf` be a subclass of `Child`, and moving the field, works

```
abstract public class Node {
    private int position; //Every Node can have a position
}

public class InnerNode extends Node { //Renamed for clarity
    List<Node> children; //Children can be InnerNodes or Leafs 
}

abstract public class LeafNode extends Node {
    //As this is no longer an extension of InnerNode, it won't have the children field.
}
```

This model makes more sense IMO. Every LeafNode and InnerNode are considered Nodes, but only InnerNodes have children.

If you want, you could even add an abstract getter to `Node` to return children, and have `LeafNode` return null or an empty list:

```
abstract public class Node {
    private int position; //Every Node can have a position

    public abstract List<Node> getChildren();
}

public class InnerNode extends Node { //Renamed for clarity
    List<Node> children; //Children can be InnerNodes or Leafs 

    public List<Node> getChildren(){
        return new ArrayList<>(children);
    }
}

abstract public class LeafNode extends Node {
    //As this is no longer an extension of InnerNode, it won't have the children field.

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return new ArrayList<>(); //Empty
    }
}
```

This accomplishes roughly what you set out to do - only some Nodes (InnerNodes) will actually have children, but you can attempt to access the children of an arbitrary Node instance without casting. The following is now possible:

```
Node n = ...
List<Node> children = n.getChildren();
```

Comment: Your code is very close to what I wanted to achieve. I just left everything as is, but now return null or empty array when children is being queried in the root node. I guess I was looking for something that isn't supported by Java or Object Oriented programming for that matter. I was looking for a way to omit certain traits of a parent - but the absence of a trait does not necessarily equate to the impossibility of the trait. So yea, empty or null works for omission purposes. Like if a parent has a child who cannot have a child, then the child has 0 children. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing as it uses parent/children relationships in terms of reality and programming without specifying which you mean. However, I think I have a general understanding as to what you are asking.

I believe what you are looking for is the Composite Pattern 
(See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

In the following implementation, `Child` and `Childless` have become part of the Composite pattern and has been abstracted an extra layer from `Root` by adding a `Person` class.

So you would have

```
abstract public class Root {
    //attributes that everything has
}

abstract public class Person extends Root {
    protected int position; //All children have parents
    //other attributes
}

abstract public class Child extends Person {
    protected List<Person> children; //But only Child has more children
    //other attributes
}

abstract public class Childless extends Person{
    //attributes
}
```

`Person` is the "component" and now has the `position` field because every child has a position in the list of the parent.

`Child` is the "composite" and now has the `children` field because every child that is not barren can have more children.

`Childless` is the "leaf" because it can no longer have more children.

Also, keep in mind that fields that are `private` cannot be accessed by subclasses, so use `protected` instead.

Comment: What's the correlation between the Root and Person class in your example? I assume your Person class is suppose to be the Root class? If that is the case, then that means that Root has a position. But it shouldn't because Root does not have a parent.

Comment: All `Person`s (people) are children of somebody else. A `Child` is a `Person` and someone who is `Childless` is also a `Person`. A `Person` who can have children is a `Child`, whereas a `Person` who cannot have children is `Childless`. (I actually made a typo in my answer. List<Root> is supposed to be List<Person>)

Comment: If you use `Root` for anything else other than to hold a list of children, you can just have `Person` extend `Root`

Comment: Let's look at it from a program perspective, and not real life. Maybe that was the confusing part. But I want a Root class that has some attributes shared among all other sub classes. A Child class of the Root shares the root's attributes and the position attribute (plus some others). Then a Childless class shares the same attributes as the Child class, but it just doesn't have children - so yeah like a leaf. Your model introduced a Person class but it doesn't correlate back to a Root class.

Comment: I've updated the question to refer to a leaf instead of a childless to make it less confusing.

Comment: Getting closer... but the Root doesn't have children. I need the root to have children. Anyway, I've decided for now to keep the children as a shared attribute across all Node. The leaf would just return an empty list if there isn't suppose to be children. This can be said for any attributes that must be omitted in the leaf class.